# How to get only a filename?

Tags: vb6

Using VB6

Code.

```
Dim posn As Integer, i As Integer
    Dim fName As String
    posn = 0
    For i = 1 To Len(flname)
        If (Mid(flname, i, 1) = "\") Then posn = i
    Next i
    fName = Right(flname, Len(flname) - posn)
    posn = InStr(fName, ".")
        If posn <> 0 Then
           fName = Left(fName, posn - 1)
       End If
    GetFileName = fName



FileName: Clockings8.mis06042009 120442.fin
```

But it is showing a filename is “Clockings8”. It should show “Clockings8.mis06042009 120442”

How to modify a code?

Need vb6 code Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bit cleaner to use the `Scripting.FileSystemObject` component.  Try:

```
Dim fso as New Scripting.FileSystemObject
GetFileName = fso.GetBaseName(fname)
```

The reason why your code stops short is that InStr works from the beginning of the string to the end and stops wherever it finds a match.  The filename "Clockings8.mis06042009 120442.fin" contains two periods.  For this reason, you should use InStrRev instead to start the search from the end of the string.

Comment: There is also [GetFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264499.aspx), which includes the extension (to save others from searching like me, who needed a VB6 equivalent of `Path.FileName`)

Answer (score 2):

Going with FileSystemObject's GetBaseName like David suggests is a good idea.  If you can't or don't want to (and there are reasons why you might not want to) work with the FileSystemObject there's a simple solution:  Remove all characters from a filename string starting with the last dot in the name.

Here's what I mean:

```
Dim fn As String
fn = "Clockings8.mis06042009 120442.fin"

Dim idx As Integer
idx = InStrRev(fn, ".")
GetFileName = Mid(fn, 1, idx - 1)
```

If your filename does not have an extenstion but has a dot somewhere in the filename string, then this method will return bad results.